# Input Field showing background color at the end on iPhone devices

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have website which we are accessing on the iPhone devices where the input fields are showing background color at the end which overlap the input field.

the css which we have configured as

```
.digit-group input, .otpdigit-group input {         
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0;
            -moz-appearance: none !important;
            appearance: none !important;          
            width: 17px;
            height: 17px !important;
            border: none;
            line-height: 17px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 1px;
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }
```

But the button doesn't render as expected.

This is how its rendered on iPhone devices. This issue happens only on iphone devices. The OTP text is not shown where background color overlap at the end.

[image]

Comment: I cannot confirm that error here. Is it an issue special to the IPhone? Which version? Questions to the code: wich background overlaps ... in your css no background has been advised to the inputs? And the html including css to wrapper(s) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand right: input is `type="button`?

Maybe ...
Buttons have a native padding if not set to zero.
Not only on IPhones.

Please try to add: `padding: 0` (!important optional)
... and/or just for testing: set width to `width: 30px`.

Comment: It was just padding issue. Thanks buddy.